# Creating Couchbase views in code: First query returns 0 rows, index builds in background

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-view, couchbase-java-api

I am creating a view in code using the Couchbase Java API 2.1.2 like this:

```
DefaultView view = DefaultView.create(viewName, jsMapFunctionAsString);
List<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
views.add(view);
DesignDocument doc = DesignDocument.create(name, views);
bucket.bucketManager().insertDesignDocument(doc);
```

Calling `ViewResult result = bucket.query(ViewQuery.from(name, viewName))` directly after inserting the document, `viewResult.success()` always returns true, but both iterators `rows()` and `iterator` return 0 rows (there are definitely results present. When I execute the view in the web interface, it returns correct values).

The workaround I found after several hours is to call `query` twice with enough waiting time in between like

```
ViewResult result = bucket.query(ViewQuery.from(name, viewName));
Thread.sleep(10000);
result = bucket.query(ViewQuery.from(name, viewName));
```

The second call will then return the correct result.

It seems as if Couchbase has to build the index for the query first but returns directly, even before the index has been built.
Waiting 10 seconds is of course not optimal, maybe creating the index will take more time in the future.

So my question is, how can I make sure, that I only wait until the index has been built?
Is this a bug in the API?

Comment: @Bohemian With version 3 they introduced an SQL-like query language called N1QL. Haven't tried that yet.
We are very happy with Couchbase, but we don't need too many queries, either.

Comment: @Sebastian There is a [developer preview](http://docs.couchbase.com/4.0/admin/whats-new.html#topic_hdg_nkd_54) of Couchbase Server 4 which has support for N1QL, Global secondary indexes and multi-dimensional spatial indexes which you might want to play with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `stale` method and set it to false in the `ViewQuery`, this will force to wait for the indexation to finish before returning results.

Comment: That is nice! I'll check it on Monday.

Comment: Just realize that by doing this, you may take a performance hit on view querying if you do not size your cluster for doing stale=false.

Comment: @Kirk Good to know. Since we will not have dynamically inserted views in production, this will not be an issue for us.